Most up to date explanation explaining the stability of high spin multiplicity (multiplicity=2S+1 ) states?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hund%27s_rules:

"However, accurate quantum-mechanical calculations (starting in the 1970s)... singly occupied orbitals are less effectively screened or shielded from the nucleus, so that such orbitals contract and electron–nucleus attraction energy becomes greater in magnitude (or decreases algebraically)."

Where do I find these calculations, papers, or data?

You have asked this same question across P.SE, C.SE and now here. Why do you think you will get a better answer? In fact, due to the vast increase in computational power, why not just do the calculations yourself?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The paragraph on Wikipedia you are citing reads in full

Two different physical explanations have been given[5] for the increased stability of high multiplicity states. In the early days of quantum mechanics, it was proposed that electrons in different orbitals are further apart, so that electron–electron repulsion energy is reduced. However, accurate quantum-mechanical calculations (starting in the 1970s) have shown that the reason is that the electrons in singly occupied orbitals are less effectively screened or shielded from the nucleus, so that such orbitals contract and electron–nucleus attraction energy becomes greater in magnitude (or decreases algebraically).

According to the same article, reference 5 is Levine's book Quantum Chemistry, where you should be able to find the answer you are looking for.
Yet, I find the Wikipedia explanation weird. The question applies to the stability of the low-spin vs high-spin states for a given electron configuration. This is easily understood already at the Hartree-Fock level of theory: electrons of opposite spin only interact through the repulsive Coulomb interaction, while electrons of the same spin also experience an attractive exchange interaction; a term where you have more electrons of the same spin is therefore lower in energy than a term where you have less electrons of the same spin on a given open shell. Maximizing the number of same spin electrons on a shell also means maximizing the number of unpaired electrons on that shell, which is the same as maximizing the multiplicity.
